# Excel VBA: How to Unfilter Only One Autofilter Range at a Time? Code Provided

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

Thanks for coming to this thread.

**What I have:**

-A report with an autofilter on rows A:G

**What I need:**

-Circumstantial code that unfilters a specific column if there is a filter on it.

-Running my code below unfilters the entire range of A:G.

-In this instance, I only want "F" unfiltered, leaving any other filters alone if they are filtered.

```
With Sheets("DATA")
    If .Range("F1").AutoFilter = True Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$59826").AutoFilter Field:=6
    Else
    End If
End With
```

Any and all ideas are greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: Your code looks fine to me,I also tested it and when I try it it does exactly as you ask for, removes autofilter from the single field.

Comment: When I run the code it removes the autofilter entirely.

Comment: However, it also removes other fields that have already been filtered. So the autofilter will be reset in Columns B and C if they are filtered. I actually answered my own question, but I dont have enough rep to answer it. Heres the code:Addr = Split(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address, "$")
    lastRow = Addr(UBound(Addr))
        For r = lastRow To 1 Step -1
            If Len(Cells(r, "A").Value) Then
            lastRow = r
        Exit For
    End If
    Next
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=6

Comment: As a side note, if any answers, past or present, have answered your question, be sure to accept them by clicking the checkmark next to them. It's the SO way :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub UnFilter()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("DATA")
With ws
    If .AutoFilterMode = True Then
        If Not Intersect(.AutoFilter.Range, .Range("G1")) Is Nothing Then
            .Range("$A$1:$G$59826").AutoFilter Field:=.Range("G:G").Column
        End If
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

This line in your code:

```
If .Range("F1").AutoFilter = True
```

... actually turns off the filtering for the whole sheet. Instead my code checks if the sheet is filtered with:

```
If .AutoFilterMode = True Then
```

It then checks if the filter includes column G with:

```
If Not Intersect(.AutoFilter.Range, .Range("G1")) Is Nothing Then
```

I made a couple of changes to make your code a little more flexible. It also enables Intellisense for the `ws` object, which is helpful. (I always find the various `Filter`-related properties and methods confusing, especially without auto-completion.)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
Sub UnfilterColumn()

    With Worksheets("DATA")
        If Not Worksheets("DATA").AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=6
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Nothing changes when it runs. I have a filter on another column and on G.

Comment: If the filter you want to remove is on column G, then use Field:=7

Comment: Oops, right you are, I had it on 6 still. However, it still fails if the filter is on another part of the sheet, e.g., column I. Then it passes the `Not is Nothing` test, but has an `Error 1004` on the `Field:=6` line`

Comment: Huh. If I filter on columns 1, 2 and 6, this code removes the filter on column 6, leaving filters on 1 and 2 intact. It also works for me if I don't have a filter on column 6 to start. I'm using Excel 2010; I wonder if that makes a difference.

Comment: What it you only have a filter on column I?

Comment: BTW Doug, I recognised your name from the microsoft.public.excel.programming group - nice to see some of the old crowd in SO.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work if a range that doesn't include column 6 is filtered.Your intersect code will take care of that, I see

Comment: SO has filled the hole that microsoft.public.excel.programming group left, and then some. Thanks for remembering!

Answer (score 2):

I just entered the simple code below in the module and it worked fine for me. You will want to alter your data range and field to match your data. I'm clearing a filter with data in columns A through M. Field 8 is column H.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$M").AutoFilter Field:=8
```