# Remove an autofilter from a range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Consider the following VBA that adds an autofilter with two criterion:

```
Sub FilterRows()
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="1"
.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="2"
End With
End Sub
```

This adds an autofilter to the sheet with two criterion, one on column C and one on D.

How do I turn off the second filter, that is, remove the criterion on field 3 while leaving the first intact?

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17976432/478884

Comment: Columns B and C (not C and D) ?

Comment: Short answer, just do `.AutoFilter field:=3`, but for a better response, refer to the link provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```vb
Sub FilterRows()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="1"
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="2"
    End With
End Sub

Sub RemoveOneFilter()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If Not .AutoFilterMode = True Then Exit Sub
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=3
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahhhh, silly me, I was trying Criterion1:="" and such and none of them worked.